# copy npm cache into private registry

Tags: npm, nexus, sonatype

Is there a way to copy npm package cache to private registry?
As registry is used sonatype nexus.

I can upload package to registry one by one over gui, but when there is over 500 packages, then it is quite ineffective.

One thought is to use npm(proxy)repo, but it has timeouts and npn(hosted) is more preferable way.

As result should be use npm in offline mode. (Installed packages will be still the same)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way how to do it:

```
$ npm set registry "http://your private registry/"
$ npm login
$ for x in */*/package.tgz ; do npm publish $x --access public; done
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case I needed to specify `pm publish $x --registry=...` in addition. Without this nexus refused to accept the package